# Return alert if value goes empty in js

Tags: javascript

I intend that if the user does not select a row in the table that returns an alert with that information as follows:

```
$(document).on("click", ".desativ_forn", function(){
  var desaf = document.querySelector('input[name="update"]:checked').value;
  if(desaf == null){
        alert("Tem de selecionar um Fornecedor!");
        $('#minhaDiv44').show();
   }else{
   }
 });
```

I also tried it this way:

```
$(document).on("click", ".desativ_forn", function(){
  if(document.querySelector('input[name="update"]:checked').value == null){
        alert("Tem de selecionar um Fornecedor!");
        $('#minhaDiv44').show();
   }else{
  var desaf = document.querySelector('input[name="update"]:checked').value;
  
   }
 });
```

But instead of returning the alert, this error is returned on the console for not selecting any:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Intended that if no line was selected, the alert would return

html:

```
$(function () { 
$('.limp-forn').on("click", function() {
$("#tabfor tbody").empty();
  $.getJSON('perfilfor.php', function (data) {

    var linha = ``; 

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
       Id = data[i][0];
       DataRegisto = data[i][1];
       Fornecedor = data[i][2];
       Nif = data[i][3];
       Contato = data[i][4];
       Morada = data[i][5];
       Postal = data[i][6];
       Email = data[i][7];
       Descricao = data[i][8];
       Nome = data[i][9];
   
       linha += `<tr class="table__row">
       <td  class="table__content" data-heading="Atualizar"><input type="radio" name="update" id="update" value="${ Id }"></td>    
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Registo"><span style="color:#ffffff">${ DataRegisto }</span></td> 
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Fornecedor"><span style="color:#ffffff">${ Fornecedor }</span></td>
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="NIF"><span style="color:#ffffff">${ Nif }</span></td>
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Contato"><span style="color:#ffffff">${ Contato }</span></td> 
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Morada"><span style="color:#ffffff">${ Morada }</span></td>
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="CEP"><span style="color:#ffffff">${ Postal }</span></td> 
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Email"><span style="color:#ffffff">${ Email }</span></td>
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Ativo"><span style="color:#ffffff">${ Descricao }</span></td>
       <td class="table__content" data-heading="Colaborador"><span style="color:#ffffff">${ Nome }</span></td>     
       </tr>`; 
    }
});
});
});
```

Comment: Can you include the html code?

Comment: can you share your HTML too?

Comment: `.querySelector()` returns `null` when there's no element that would match the given selector not `.value`

Comment: @tonoslfx I added html that is built with a dynamic table in js.

Comment: @Gilang Pratama I added html that is built with a dynamic table in js.

Comment: @Andreas But if I select a line it works well, I just need to show the alert if they don't. The if I built is not working

Comment: _"But if I select a line it works well"_ - Because the selector in your `.querySelector()` call matches an element. No match, no `.value` - Just adjust that part in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".desativ_forn", function(){
  let desaf = document.querySelector('input[name="update"]:checked');
  if(!desaf){
        alert("Tem de selecionar um Fornecedor!");
        $('#minhaDiv44').show();
   }else{
   }
 })
```

@Andreas is right. As he said `.querySelector()` returns null probably and if we want to check the value, first we must check if the element is `defined`.